# Extract data between a pattern from a text file

Tags: r, regex, import

I am working with a text file where data look like below

```
*******************************
Sensor 1028 at site 101
SID = 16384
Tag = AI.1028.BT.VOLT
04/07/16 05:00:00  12.65
04/07/16 06:00:00  12.64
04/07/16 07:00:00  12.68
04/07/16 08:00:00  13.08
04/07/16 09:00:00  13.76
*******************************
Sensor 1171 at well 102
SID = 20062
Tag = AI.1171.WT.LEV
04/07/16 05:00:00  0.95
04/07/16 06:00:00  0.90
04/07/16 07:00:00  0.82
04/07/16 08:00:00  0.71
04/07/16 09:00:00  0.59
04/07/16 10:00:00  0.48
```

I want to be able to extract the data for each tag and create a data frame as below-

```
Tag  Timestamp          Value
1028 04/07/16 05:00:00  12.65
1028 04/07/16 06:00:00  12.64
1028 04/07/16 07:00:00  12.68
1028 04/07/16 08:00:00  13.08
1028 04/07/16 09:00:00  13.76
1171 04/07/16 05:00:00  0.95
1171 04/07/16 06:00:00  0.90
1171 04/07/16 07:00:00  0.82
1171 04/07/16 08:00:00  0.71
1171 04/07/16 09:00:00  0.59
1171 04/07/16 10:00:00  0.48
```

Tag is the numeric part in the patter such as 1028 in "Tag = AI.1028.BT.VOLT" and 1171 in "Tag = AI.1171.WT.LEV".

I have looked at other questions on similar lines but I am relatively new to R and other than importing the text file using `readLines` and extracting the pattern using `grep`, I couldn't do anything.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Importing the text file and using regex sounds like a good solution, what's the problem with just doing that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the `data.table` package, I would approach it as follows:

```
sensortext <- readLines('sensors.txt')

library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(txt = sensortext[!grepl(pattern = '\\*+', sensortext)])

DT <- DT[, grp := cumsum(grepl('Sensor', txt))
         ][, `:=` (tag = as.numeric(gsub('^.*(\\d+{4}).*','\\1', grep('Tag =', txt, value = TRUE))),
                   sid = as.numeric(gsub('^.*(\\d+{5}).*','\\1', grep('SID = ', txt, value = TRUE))),
                   type = strsplit(grep('Sensor ', txt, value = TRUE),' ')[[1]][4],
                   type.nr = as.numeric(gsub('^.*(\\d+{3}).*','\\1', grep('Sensor ', txt, value = TRUE)))), 
           by = grp
           ][, .SD[4:.N], by = grp
             ][, c('datetime','value') := tstrsplit(txt, '\\s+{2}', type.convert = TRUE)
               ][, c('grp','txt') := NULL
                 ][, datetime := as.POSIXct(strptime(datetime, "%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S"))]
```

which gives:

> ```
> > DT
>      tag   sid type type.nr            datetime value
>  1: 1028 16384 site     101 2016-07-04 05:00:00 12.65
>  2: 1028 16384 site     101 2016-07-04 06:00:00 12.64
>  3: 1028 16384 site     101 2016-07-04 07:00:00 12.68
>  4: 1028 16384 site     101 2016-07-04 08:00:00 13.08
>  5: 1028 16384 site     101 2016-07-04 09:00:00 13.76
>  6: 1171 20062 well     102 2016-07-04 05:00:00  0.95
>  7: 1171 20062 well     102 2016-07-04 06:00:00  0.90
>  8: 1171 20062 well     102 2016-07-04 07:00:00  0.82
>  9: 1171 20062 well     102 2016-07-04 08:00:00  0.71
> 10: 1171 20062 well     102 2016-07-04 09:00:00  0.59
> 11: 1171 20062 well     102 2016-07-04 10:00:00  0.48
> ```

*Explanation*:

- With the `readLines` function you read the textfile. After that, you convert it to a 1 column datatable `data.table(txt = sensortext[!grepl(pattern = '\\*+', sensortext)])`.
- With `[, grp := cumsum(grepl('Sensor', txt))]` you create a grouping variable that separates the different dataparts. `grepl('Sensor', txt)` creates a logical value detecting the lines that start with `Sensor` (and indicate the start of a new datapart). Using `cumsum` on that creates an grouping variable.
- With `tag = as.numeric(gsub('^.*(\\d+{4}).*','\\1', grep('Tag =', txt, value = TRUE)))` you extract the tag-number (as well as for `sid`, `type` & `type.nr`).
- With `[, .SD[4:.N], by = grp]` you remove the first three lines per group (because they do not contain data and the needed info is already extracted in the previous steps).
- With `[, c('datetime','value') := tstrsplit(txt, '\\s+{2}', type.convert = TRUE)]` you convert the data which is still in text format in the `txt` column into three data columns. The `type.convert = TRUE` makes sure that the `value` column gets the right format (numeric in this case).
- Remove the `grp` and `txt` columns with `[, c('grp','txt') := NULL]` (because they are not needed anymore).
- And finally convert the `datetime` column to `POSIXct` format with `as.POSIXct(strptime(datetime, "%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S"))`.

To see what each step does, you can also use the following code:

```
DT[, grp := cumsum(grepl('Sensor', txt))]
DT[, `:=` (tag = as.numeric(gsub('^.*(\\d+{4}).*','\\1', grep('Tag =', txt, value = TRUE))),
           sid = as.numeric(gsub('^.*(\\d+{5}).*','\\1', grep('SID = ', txt, value = TRUE))),
           type = strsplit(grep('Sensor ', txt, value = TRUE),' ')[[1]][4],
           type.nr = as.numeric(gsub('^.*(\\d+{3}).*','\\1', grep('Sensor ', txt, value = TRUE)))),
   by = grp][]
DT <- DT[, .SD[4:.N], by = grp][]
DT[, c('datetime','value') := tstrsplit(txt, '\\s+{2}', type.convert = TRUE)][]
DT[, c('grp','txt') := NULL][]
DT[, datetime := as.POSIXct(strptime(datetime, "%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S"))][]
```

Adding `[]` to each line, makes sure that the result gets printed to the console.

---

An alternative with base R:

```
sensortext <- readLines('sensors.txt')

rawlist <- split(sensortext, cumsum(grepl(pattern = '\\*+', sensortext)))
l <- lapply(rawlist, function(x) read.fwf(textConnection(x[-c(1:4)]), widths = c(17,7), header = FALSE))
reps <- sapply(l, nrow)

df <- do.call(rbind, l)
df$V1 <- strptime(df$V1, '%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S')
names(df) <- c('datetime','value')

df$tag <- rep(as.numeric(gsub('^.*(\\d+{4}).*','\\1', grep('Tag =', sensortext, value = TRUE))), reps)
df$sid  <- rep(as.numeric(gsub('^.*(\\d+{5}).*','\\1', grep('SID = ', sensortext, value = TRUE))), reps)
df$type  <- rep(sapply(strsplit(grep('Sensor ', sensortext, value = TRUE),' '), '[', 4), reps)
df$type.nr <- rep(as.numeric(gsub('^.*(\\d+{3}).*','\\1', grep('Sensor ', sensortext, value = TRUE))), reps)
```

which gives the same result:

> ```
> > df
>                datetime value  tag   sid type type.nr
> 1.1 2016-07-04 05:00:00 12.65 1028 16384 site     101
> 1.2 2016-07-04 06:00:00 12.64 1028 16384 site     101
> 1.3 2016-07-04 07:00:00 12.68 1028 16384 site     101
> 1.4 2016-07-04 08:00:00 13.08 1028 16384 site     101
> 1.5 2016-07-04 09:00:00 13.76 1028 16384 site     101
> 2.1 2016-07-04 05:00:00  0.95 1171 20062 well     102
> 2.2 2016-07-04 06:00:00  0.90 1171 20062 well     102
> 2.3 2016-07-04 07:00:00  0.82 1171 20062 well     102
> 2.4 2016-07-04 08:00:00  0.71 1171 20062 well     102
> 2.5 2016-07-04 09:00:00  0.59 1171 20062 well     102
> 2.6 2016-07-04 10:00:00  0.48 1171 20062 well     102
> ```

Comment: @ Procrastinatus Maximus - Thank you for taking out time and giving such a detailed explanation. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a base R solution. We locate the rows that start with `Sensor` or a date, and then extract the latter rows between each pair of `Sensor` rows.

```
date_rows <- grep("^\\d+/", s)
#  [1]  4  5  6  7  8 13 14 15 16 17 18
sensor_rows <- grep("^Sensor", s)
# [1]  1 10

tab <- lapply(seq_along(sensor_rows), function(x) {
  tag <- sub("^Sensor (\\d+)+.*", "\\1", s[sensor_rows[x]])
  last_row <- ifelse(is.na(sensor_rows[x + 1L]), length(s), sensor_rows[x + 1L] - 1L)
  rows <- seq.int(sensor_rows[x], last_row)
  # extract date rows between the current tag line and the next
  values <- s[intersect(rows, date_rows)]
  data.frame(tag = rep(tag, length(values)), value = values, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
})
tab <- do.call("rbind", tab)
```

So far, we've assigned a tag to each line of data and moved them into a table.

```
head(tab)
#    tag                    value
# 1 1028 04/07/16 05:00:00  12.65
# 2 1028 04/07/16 06:00:00  12.64
# 3 1028 04/07/16 07:00:00  12.68
# 4 1028 04/07/16 08:00:00  13.08
# 5 1028 04/07/16 09:00:00  13.76
# 6 1171  04/07/16 05:00:00  0.95
```

All that's left is to split the strings in the value column. Incidentally this would be a one-liner with data.table's tstrsplit.

```
split_values <- t(data.frame(strsplit(tab$value, "\\s+"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
colnames(split_values) <- c("date", "time", "value")
tab <- as.data.frame(cbind(tag = tab[, "tag"], split_values), stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
                     row.names = FALSE)

tab$timestamp <- paste(tab$date, tab$time)
tab <- tab[, c("tag", "timestamp", "value")]
str(tab)
# 'data.frame': 11 obs. of  3 variables:
#  $ tag      : chr  "1028" "1028" "1028" "1028" ...
#  $ timestamp: chr  "04/07/16 05:00:00" "04/07/16 06:00:00" "04/07/16 07:00:00" "04/07/16 08:00:00" ...
#  $ value    : chr  "12.65" "12.64" "12.68" "13.08" ...
```

And here's how I read the data:

```
s = scan(what = "character", fill = TRUE, blank.lines.skip = TRUE, sep = "\n",
     text = "Sensor 1028 at site 101
SID = 16384
Tag = AI.1028.BT.VOLT
04/07/16 05:00:00  12.65
04/07/16 06:00:00  12.64
04/07/16 07:00:00  12.68
04/07/16 08:00:00  13.08
04/07/16 09:00:00  13.76
*******************************
Sensor 1171 at well 102
SID = 20062
Tag = AI.1171.WT.LEV
04/07/16 05:00:00  0.95
04/07/16 06:00:00  0.90
04/07/16 07:00:00  0.82
04/07/16 08:00:00  0.71
04/07/16 09:00:00  0.59
04/07/16 10:00:00  0.48")
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach using dplyr, tidyr, and a text reshaping package I have on GitHub for the splitting of the file.

### Your Data

```
   x <- c("*******************************", "Sensor 1028 at site 101", 
        "SID = 16384", "Tag = AI.1028.BT.VOLT", "04/07/16 05:00:00  12.65", 
        "04/07/16 06:00:00  12.64", "04/07/16 07:00:00  12.68", "04/07/16 08:00:00  13.08", 
        "04/07/16 09:00:00  13.76", "*******************************", 
        "Sensor 1171 at well 102", "SID = 20062", "Tag = AI.1171.WT.LEV", 
        "04/07/16 05:00:00  0.95", "04/07/16 06:00:00  0.90", "04/07/16 07:00:00  0.82", 
        "04/07/16 08:00:00  0.71", "04/07/16 09:00:00  0.59", "04/07/16 10:00:00  0.48"
        )
```

### Code to read and reshape the data

```
if (!require("pacman")) install.packages("pacman"); library(pacman)
p_load_current_gh('trinker/textshape')
p_load(dplyr, tidyr)

## x <- readLines('myfile.txt') 
split_match(x, "\\*{5,}", regex=TRUE) %>%  ## find multi asterisks and split
    lapply(function(x){

        data_frame(Timestamp_Value = x[-c(1:3)]) %>%  ## make dataframe of n-first 3 elements
            separate(Timestamp_Value, c('Timestamp', 'Value'), sep = "\\s{2,}") %>%  # split timestamp and value apart
            mutate(Tag = gsub("(^[A-Za-z ]+)(\\d+)(\\s.+$)", "\\2", x[1])) %>%  ## add Tag with regex gsub
            select(3, 1:2)
    }) %>%
    bind_rows() %>%  ## bind list of data frames together
    mutate(
        Tag = as.numeric(Tag),
        Timestamp = as.POSIXct(strptime(Timestamp, "%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S")),
        Value = as.numeric(Value)
    )  ## add appropriate classes
```

### Yields:

```
Source: local data frame [11 x 3]

     Tag           Timestamp Value
   (dbl)              (time) (dbl)
1   1028 2016-07-04 05:00:00 12.65
2   1028 2016-07-04 06:00:00 12.64
3   1028 2016-07-04 07:00:00 12.68
4   1028 2016-07-04 08:00:00 13.08
5   1028 2016-07-04 09:00:00 13.76
6   1171 2016-07-04 05:00:00  0.95
7   1171 2016-07-04 06:00:00  0.90
8   1171 2016-07-04 07:00:00  0.82
9   1171 2016-07-04 08:00:00  0.71
10  1171 2016-07-04 09:00:00  0.59
11  1171 2016-07-04 10:00:00  0.48
```