# How to Convert a Line into Multiple Columns in R

Tags: r, data.table

I have many text files and all these files include a line which starts with the same comment.

```
"HDR TIME_YMD=2001-02-16 T 00:00:00"
"HDR TIME_YMD=2001-03-18 T 00:00:00"
```

etc.

I want to be able to change the line into two columns and create a data frame as below.

```
Year    Month
2001    02 (or February)
2001    03 (or March)
```

I have found similar answers from other questions. With the benefit of [Extract data between a pattern from a text file in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37663246/extract-data-between-a-pattern-from-a-text-file-in-r?rq=1) the code that I have imitated is as follows, but I couldn't code the "Month" column.

```
DT <- DT[, `:=` (Year = as.numeric(gsub('^.*(\\d+{4}).*','\\1', 
                        grep('HDR TIME_YMD=', txt, value = TRUE))), Month=????
```

Another answers I am looking for;

I want to convert the data into three data columns as `'Longitude','Latitude','TWC'`

```
  Year  Month  Longitude  Latitude     TWC
1 2001  02         130.5    -16.5     6.935
2 2001  02         131.5    -16.5    13.912
3 2001  03         132.5    -16.5    13.244
4 2001  03         133.5    -16.5    15.556
5 2001  03         134.5    -16.5    21.380
```

I am very noob to R and I may need a detailed explanation. Thanks!

Thanks @Psidom. I have trouble with the slipped columns, 'Longitude','Latitude','TWC'. Here's my code.

```
L<-readLines("Document1.txt")
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(txt = L[!grepl(pattern = '\\*+', L)])
DT[, c('Year', 'Month') := tstrsplit(grep('HDR TIME_YMD=', txt, value = TRUE), "=|-")[2:3]]
DT <- DT[, .SD[20:.N]][]
DT[, c('Longitude','Latitude','TWC') := tstrsplit(txt, '\\s+{3}', type.convert = TRUE)][]
DT[, c('txt') := NULL][]
```

It gives me this solution.

```
   Year Month               Longitude Latitude                      TWC
1: 2001    02            137.50 -16.50    18.57            137.50 -16.50
2: 2001    02  138.50 -16.50 32767.000       NA  138.50 -16.50 32767.000
3: 2001    02  139.50 -16.50 32767.000       NA  139.50 -16.50 32767.000
```

I want them to look like this.

```
   Year Month Longitude Latitude       TWC
1: 2001    02    137.50   -16.50    18.570          
2: 2001    02    138.50   -16.50 32767.000       
3: 2001    02    139.50   -16.50 32767.000
```

Comment: For the `longitude` and `latitude` part, why would you specify `\\s+{3}` as separator? What do you want to split on?

Comment: That's the point. I have no idea, just imitating the other solutions..

Comment: @Procrastinatus Maximus Do you have any suggestions for the solution? I tried but >DT[, c('Longitude','Latitude','TWC') := tstrsplit(txt, '\\s+{3}', type.convert = TRUE)][] does not work for me. What does the '\\s+{2}' stands for?

Answer (score 2):

If the time stamp is formatted as well as you have shown, you can just `split` it and use `index` to get the year and month:

```
library(data.table)
dt[, c("Year", "Month") := tstrsplit(TimeStamp, "=|-")[2:3]]
dt
#                            TimeStamp Year Month
#1: HDR TIME_YMD=2001-02-16 T 00:00:00 2001    02
#2: HDR TIME_YMD=2001-02-16 T 00:00:00 2001    02
#3: HDR TIME_YMD=2001-02-16 T 00:00:00 2001    02
```

Where `dt` is:

```
dt = data.table(TimeStamp = c("HDR TIME_YMD=2001-02-16 T 00:00:00", 
                              "HDR TIME_YMD=2001-02-16 T 00:00:00", 
                              "HDR TIME_YMD=2001-02-16 T 00:00:00"))
dt
#                             TimeStamp
# 1: HDR TIME_YMD=2001-02-16 T 00:00:00
# 2: HDR TIME_YMD=2001-02-16 T 00:00:00
# 3: HDR TIME_YMD=2001-02-16 T 00:00:00
```

Comment: Thanks @Psidom. I have trouble with the slipped columns, 'Longitude','Latitude','TWC'. Here's my code. `>L<-readLines("Document1.txt")
>library(data.table)
>DT <- data.table(txt = L[!grepl(pattern = '\\*+', L)])
>DT[, c('Year', 'Month') := tstrsplit(grep('HDR TIME_YMD=', txt, value = TRUE), "=|-")[2:3]]
>DT <- DT[, .SD[20:.N]][]
>DT[, c('Longitude','Latitude','TWC') := tstrsplit(txt, '\\s+{3}', type.convert = TRUE)][]
>DT[, c('txt') := NULL][]`

Answer (score 0):

An option is to convert it to a `DateTime` class and then extract the components

```
library(lubridate)
dt[, c("Year", "Month") := {t1 <- ymd_hms(TimeStamp); .(year(t1), month(t1))}]
dt
#                            TimeStamp Year Month
#1: HDR TIME_YMD=2001-02-16 T 00:00:00 2001     2
#2: HDR TIME_YMD=2001-02-16 T 00:00:00 2001     2
#3: HDR TIME_YMD=2001-02-16 T 00:00:00 2001     2
```

#### data

```
dt = data.table(TimeStamp = c("HDR TIME_YMD=2001-02-16 T 00:00:00", 
                          "HDR TIME_YMD=2001-02-16 T 00:00:00", 
                          "HDR TIME_YMD=2001-02-16 T 00:00:00"))
```

Comment: Thank you @akrun, I will check out your solution soon.