# Two digital of year became commas

Tags: r

My final purpose is only keep the column of Time and Concentration, but before I skip all rows in the top, I want to keep the date"9/12/2017" (I will add to the Time column later).

There is a annoying "Comment for Sample 1:" in the end, I need to get rid of it. The biggest problem is when I tried to save the date, it not came out with"9/12/2017", but "9/12/17,,". I don't know why it goes that way, it may be affected by the comment line in the end, two digital of year became commas.

```
Sample File E:\CPC 091217\091217CPC3.C07
Model   3007
Sample #    1
Start Date  9/12/2017
Start Time  10:29:57
Sample Length   4:14:37
Averaging Interval (secs)   1
Title   
Instrument ID   3007-03160001 3.1
Instrument Errors   None

Time    Concentration (#/cm³)
10:29:58    4224
10:29:59    97323
10:30:00    14590
10:30:09    73716
10:30:10    70779
10:30:11    60642
10:30:12    56171

.........
Comment for Sample 1:
```

What I tried is

```
cpcFile = choose.files(default = "", caption = "           

                   SELECT  THE  CPC.csv  FILE   ",
                   multi = FALSE, filters = Filters[c("txt", "All"),],
                   index = nrow(Filters))

cpcData <- read.csv(cpcFile, skip = 16)

#helps get rid of the comment line,it works
cpcData<-cpcData[- grep("Comment", cpcData$Time),]

#however,the P6 shows "9/12/17,,"instead of " "9/12/2017"
K=readLines(cpcFile, n = 5) # read first 5 lines
header=K[[5]]                # read only the date and time
P6= substr(header, 12, 25)
```

expectation:

```
 Time            Concentration (#/cm³)
10:29:58 9/12/2017     4224
10:29:59 9/12/2017     97323
10:30:00 9/12/2017     14590
10:30:09 9/12/2017     73716
 ........
```

and P6 should be 9/12/2017 firstly, thanks!

Comment: Some inspiration: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37665045/2204410

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend sidestepping the issue of parsing the date out of the file and just parse it out of the file name instead, assuming they consistently have the date in.

Then you can use `readr::read_delim` or `readr::readfwf` depending on what exactly delimits your file, with the `skip` argument to skip the header. The footer will probably just fail to parse, but you can check that and drop it if it doesn't. You can set the date column after you load the data frame by using `string:str_extract` with a regex on the file name.