# Structuring a large text file into a dataframe using R

Tags: r, text, text-mining

I have a text file of around 20 pages with around 200 paragraphs. Each paragraph contains three lines describing information about a person like so:

```
Name: John
Age: 26
Phone number: 123421

Name: Mary
Age: 80
Phone number: NA

...
```

Now I wish to convert this large file into a dataframe where the columns represent the three variables Name, Age and Phone number and where the rows correspond to the persons.

```
Name      Age      Phone number
John      26       123421
Mary      80       NA
...       ...      ...
```

How can I convert the large text file into such a dataframe?

Comment: Similar problem: [*Extract data between a pattern from a text file*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37663246/2204410)

Comment: Can you show us a sample of the data structure once it is loaded into R?

Comment: The file appears to be in DCF format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not pretty but here is a regex option that may work depending on how the data is read in,

```
test<-
"Name: John
Age: 26
Phone number: 123421

Name: Mary
Age: 80
Phone number: NA
"
```

This is read in as:

```
[1] "Name: John\nAge: 26\nPhone number: 123421\n\nName: Mary\nAge: 80\nPhone number: NA\n"
```

Now using regex to get all matches, always catching NA's to ensure same number of rows:

```
Names<-regmatches(test, gregexpr("(?<=Name: )[a-zA-Z]+", test, perl=TRUE))

Numbers<-regmatches(test, gregexpr("(?<=Phone number: )[a-zA-Z0-9]+", test, perl=TRUE))

Age<-regmatches(test, gregexpr("(?<=Age: )[a-zA-Z0-9]+", test, perl=TRUE))

df<-data.frame(Names,Numbers,Age)
names(df)<-c("Name","Number","Age")

> df
  Name Number Age
1 John 123421  26
2 Mary     NA  80
```

Here is how to format the data for this approach if it is read in using `read.csv`

```
test<-read.csv(text=test, header=F, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
test<-list(test$V1)
test<-paste(unlist(test), collapse =" ")
>test
[1] "Name: John Age: 26 Phone number: 123421 Name: Mary Age: 80 Phone number: NA"
```

If you have last names our regex for the `Names` argument will need to be changed too:

`(?<=Name: ).+?(?=Age)`

Answer (score 2):

The `read.dcf()` from base R was built to read this type of data:

```
read.dcf(textConnection(test), all = TRUE)
```

> ```
>   Name Age Phone number
> 1 John  26       123421
> 2 Mary  80           NA
> ```

A brief description of the DCF ("Debian Control File") format can be found at `help("read.dcf")`.

#### Data

```
test <-
"Name: John
Age: 26
Phone number: 123421

Name: Mary
Age: 80
Phone number: NA
"
```

Comment: This is an awesome package I have not heard of until now, this should be considered for the accepted answer.

Comment: Thanks, @Chabo. The function is part of base R, so no packages are required.